# Pictures in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Does anyone know if there is a powershell shell command that will return a "y/n" if a picture has been uploaded to a Azure Users Profile?
We are auditing our files for HR.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 2):

There is no such command available.